# Constructing a list of Cartesian coordinates of the Icosahedron

Tags: geometry, combinatorics, polyhedra

I’m learning *Mathematica* and I need the coordinates of the Icosahedron vertices. This is my attempt at writing a program for it. The vertex coordinates are simply all cyclic permutations and sign-flips of `{GoldenRatio, 1, 0}`. My program is almost as long as writing the vertices down by hand, however. Can this be done in a more compact way in *Mathematica*?

```
signs = Flatten[Table[{i,j,k},{i,{-1,1}},{j,{-1,1}},{k,{-1,1}} ],2]
vertices = Table[RotateRight[{GoldenRatio, 1, 0}, i]\[Times]signs[[j]],{i, 3},{j, 8}]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the built-in functionality

```
PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, -(5/Sqrt[50 - 10 Sqrt[5]])}, ... }
> ```

or this short generator

```
{0,##2}~RotateLeft~#&@@@Tuples@{{1,2,3},s={-1,1},s(1+√5)/2}

ConvexHullMesh[%]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
V = Table[RotateRight[{0, (-1)^j, (-1)^Floor[j/2] GoldenRatio}, Floor[(j - 1)/4]], {j, 12}];
```

You can plot it using `ConvexHullMesh`:

```
ConvexHullMesh[V]
```

[image]